# How to customized the model of installed app in Django?

Tags: django, model, customization

Right now I was using django_comments_xtd in my site, but I wanna make modifications to the models.py of the installed app django_comments_xtd, make it customized. I just don't know how. I knew I may use something like subclass, but there is a lot of connections in those classes in the models.py, I just wanna overwrite one of them, so how should I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, using subclasses would be the best scenario in this case. Also you could get a local copy of that app and put it in your project files and edit the source directly. I've had to do this on occasion.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I just copy the app into the local directory and it works well now!

Comment: My reputation is under 15, so maybe you need to wait for a while, so sorry about that. I will voteup when I achieve 15 reputation.